# Service resource not found when trying to access service on localhost

Tags: c#, asp.net, rest, web-services

I'm following [this tutorial](https://www.guru99.com/restful-web-services.html) on how to build a REST web-service with ASP.NET, but I am having some trouble:

When accessing the address https://localhost:44397/TestService.svc, I get a message saying "*Metadata publishing for this service is currently disabled.*" I can't tell if this is important or not.

Also, when I try to access the address https://localhost:44397/TestService.svc/Test, which according to the tutorial should return "Hello", I get a "*The resource cannot be found*." message.

Any idea if I'm missing something in my code or in my config? I'm including them here:

The file: *TestService.svc.cs*:

```
namespace Test.REST
{
    [ServiceContract(Namespace = "Test.REST")]
    [AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]
    public class TestService
    {
        [WebGet(UriTemplate = "/Test")]
        public String Test()
        {
            return "Hello";
        }
    }
}
```

The file *Web.config*:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301879
  -->
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Version" value="3.0.0.0" />
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.7.2" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.7.2" />
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
      <remove name="OPTIONSVerbHandler" />
      <remove name="TRACEVerbHandler" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="*" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Antlr3.Runtime" publicKeyToken="eb42632606e9261f" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.5.0.2" newVersion="3.5.0.2" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-12.0.0.0" newVersion="12.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Optimization" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-1.1.0.0" newVersion="1.1.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="WebGrease" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-1.6.5135.21930" newVersion="1.6.5135.21930" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-5.2.7.0" newVersion="5.2.7.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
  <system.codedom>
    <compilers>
      <compiler language="c#;cs;csharp" extension=".cs" type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.CSharpCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=2.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:default /nowarn:1659;1699;1701" />
      <compiler language="vb;vbs;visualbasic;vbscript" extension=".vb" type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.VBCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=2.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:default /nowarn:41008 /define:_MYTYPE=\&quot;Web\&quot; /optionInfer+" />
    </compilers>
  </system.codedom>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="Test.REST.TestServiceAspNetAjaxBehavior">
          <webHttp />
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true"
      multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
    <services>
      <service name="Test.REST.TestService">
        <endpoint address="TestService" behaviorConfiguration="Test.REST.TestServiceAspNetAjaxBehavior"
          binding="webHttpBinding" contract="Test.REST.TestService" />
      </service>
    </services>
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

Best regards.

Comment: Hi, If you will add your controller implementation it might help

Comment: Thanks @GuyKorol, the tutorial I was following didn't mention controllers, so I didn't create one. If I create a TestController (similar to the pregenerated ValuesController), then I can also get some values back via https://localhost:44397/api/test, which is great! But I'm not sure how the application decides on this address, I can't see the string "api" anywhere in my web.config. Can I change "api" to something else? What is the use of the file TestService.svc, if the controller alone does the job?

Comment: Usually the URI is determined by the controller's name for example `RouteController` will probably be reached using 'api/Route', however you can specify the needed URI using `[Route("/desiredRoute")]`.  The guide you added, is about WCF Rest API, which is working differently, The ASP .Net controllers are a much easier way of creating a .net web application in my opinion.  This is much better tutorial: [Microsoft Tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-web-api?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio) good luck!

Comment: Cheers @GuyKorol, I will go with that. If you want, you can include your comments in an answer about it being easier for me to have a controller and perhaps a link to the other tutorial, and I'll approve it.